# access_token from Keycloak in Angular2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, keycloak

I have developed an Angular 4 app using angular-cli, I have a spring-boot server which requires keylock access_token to give access to the client. When I call endpoints I attache the token (currently hardcoded) in the Angular service class.

This works fine, but now I need to get rid of the hardcoded token.

I have the grant type, client id, client secrete and the keycloak URL which takes application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type. I got this token from the postman.

What I am looking for is the best way to get that big token from keyclock then attach the token to the Authorization header programmatically every time I make an HTTP call to my backend service.

something like this

in my keyclok-service.ts

```
header = new Headers({
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
```

});

```
 options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.header});

createAccessToken() {
const keyclock = new Keyclock('the grant type', 'the client id ', 'the cleitn secret');

return this.http.post('https:/keyclockserverurl/auth/realms/env/protocol/openid-connect/token', keyclock, this.options);
```

}

This code gives two errors
1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

2. "invalid_request" gratn_type not found

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: `"invalid_request" grant_type not found` which one is the grant type?

Comment: the first argument in the keycloak constructor as you see the value "tha grant type " is the grant -type I have changed the value for secuirity reason . But I am passing the right value.

Comment: after changing the body like this body = 'grant_type=yourGrantType&client_id=yourclientId&client_secret=yourclientSecrete'; I can see the token in the response when I checked the network call, but the client is not receiving the token and , I tried to print the token using console.log(response) it prints undefined and showing the CORS error mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, it is the way I am sending the body. As you see that in my post method I am sending the body which is a keyclok object wrapped with grant_type, client_id and client_secrete. This works only if the content type is application/json , since the content type is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', I needed to send the body in the below format

```
body = 'grant_type=yourGrantType&client_id=yourclientId&client_secret=yourclientSecrete';
```

This solved the problem 2 thats is grant_type missing . in order to fix the CROS issue , I created proxy server.

To understand how to create proxy server in angular-cli project see 
[here](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/)